# Entity Framework - Field is required but is present

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I Have a problem with entity framework: When I call "Save Changes", the method throws an Exception: "The FieldName field is required". But when I inspect modified fields are present both fields and FK field.

I have no clues about what's happening.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The code is just:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

and the entity have:

```
[Required]
[ForeignKey("FieldStateId")]
public virtual FieldState FieldState { get; set; }

public int FieldStateId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try moving [Required] to FieldStateId, not the nav property.

Comment: It works! But it works before. Magically starts to fail LOL